# Powershell start-process Runspace wont start except with -noexit flag

Tags: powershell, xaml, runspace, start-process

So i wrote this little GUI with Runspaces.
it works as expected when running it in ISE, and if i start it from a PS prompt, but when i try to run it from a Shortcut it just wont boot as long as i dont use the -noexit flag. but when using the -noexit flag it will leave the Powershell process running even after i close the GUI.

iam using this tecnuiqe for my GUI:
[Powershell GUI Template](https://github.com/1RedOne/BlogPosts/blob/master/GUI%20Part%20V/PowerShell_GUI_Template.ps1)

this is what i have in my shortcut:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -sta -WindowStyle Hidden -file "C:\Temp\Runspaceversion.ps1"

that wont work... but if i do

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -sta -WindowStyle Hidden **-noexit** -file "C:\IT\Checklist\Runspaceversion.ps1"

it works, but i get the powershell process idling when i exit the Gui....

Comment: PS can be picky about its own command line arguments, post what you've got in the shortcut with and without so we can advise.

Comment: this is what i have in my shortcut:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -sta -WindowStyle Hidden -file "C:\Temp\Runspaceversion.ps1"

that wont work... but if i do

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -sta -WindowStyle Hidden -noexit -file "C:\IT\Checklist\Runspaceversion.ps1"

it works, but i get the powershell process idling when i exit the Gui....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exit code in the template being used.

When the Window is closed, this fires...

```
    #region Window Close 
    $syncHash.Window.Add_Closed({
        Write-Verbose 'Halt runspace cleanup job processing'
        $jobCleanup.Flag = $False

        #Stop all runspaces
        $jobCleanup.PowerShell.Dispose()

    })
```

Change that block to include something like this...

```
    #region Window Close 
    $syncHash.Window.Add_Closed({
        Write-Verbose 'Halt runspace cleanup job processing'
        $jobCleanup.Flag = $False

        #Stop all runspaces
        $jobCleanup.PowerShell.Dispose()
        $jobProcessInfo = (Get-WmiObject win32_process `
        -Filter {name = 'powershell.exe' and commandline like '%PowerShell_GUI_Template.ps1%'})
        Stop-Process -Id $jobProcessInfo.ProcessId

    })
```

Of course this may be a brute force way of doing this, but I pulled down the template and this works for closing the associated host process on the closing the form Window.

This is what I have in the shortcut.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -noexit "& { D:\Scripts\PowerShellTips\PowerShell_GUI_Template.ps1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by default the PowerShell console closes, also terminating all associated runspaces and threads including the one of the form it just created.  This is because `BeginInvoke()` starts the form but then resumes the current thread.

Basically PowerShell has to be running. Instead of `BeginInvoke()` you could try `RunDialog()` which will hold the main thread until the Form is closed, at which point PowerShell will also exit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around it, with passing a Paramater with $PID killing both the session that started the GUI and as Postnote said, killing the process when exiting the GUI.